# Бот VK, параметр указан не верно или пропущен

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, бот

Пишу бота для ВК, когда запрашиваю информацию об 1 человеке из группы, всё работает - получаю имя и фамилию. Если запрашиваю информацию сразу о нескольких пользователях, то получаю исключение:

> VkNet.Exception.ParameterMissingOrInvalidException: "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer"

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using VkNet;
using VkNet.Enums.Filters;
using VkNet.Model;
using VkNet.Utils;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            VkApi vk = new VkApi(); // Объект для работы с API VK

            var webClient = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
            try
            {
                vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
                {
                    ApplicationId = *******,
                    Login = "***********",
                    Password = "***************",
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Тест");
            }

            var param = new VkParameters() { }; //Создание объекта для передачи параметров https://vk.com/dev/methods

            param.Add<string>("group_id", "oliverspeaker");
            param.Add<string>("offset", "0");
            param.Add<string>("count", "5");

            var rawJson = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("groups.getMembers", param).RawJson);

            string ids = string.Join(", ", rawJson["response"]["items"].ToArray().Select(x => x.ToString()));

            param = new VkParameters();

            param.Add<string>("user_id", ids);
            param.Add<string>("fields", "photo_100");

            var dbUsers = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("users.get", param).RawJson)["response"];

            foreach (dynamic item in dbUsers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.first_name} {item.last_name}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Конец.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам понял в чем ошибка, просто смотрел туториал по старой версии API, где был параметр user_id, а в новой версии нужно user_ids